# Debian changelog file width?

Tags: packaging, debian-policy

What is the max width in characters of a debian changelog file?

I thought it is 80 columns, but I can't find where I had read that.

I didn't find the answer in these references (unless I missed it)...

- [Debian Manuals](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dreq.en.html#changelog)
- [Debian Policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-source.html#s-dpkgchangelog)

Please include a reference if you have one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [checked by lintian](https://lintian.debian.org/tags/debian-changelog-line-too-long.html):

> The given line of the latest changelog entry is over 80 columns. Such changelog entries may look poor in terminal windows and mail messages and be annoying to read. Please wrap changelog entries at 80 columns or less where possible.

I don’t know whether it’s documented anywhere else.